Problem when running terminal command: "pip install anonympy"
I'm on an MacBook Pro w/ M1 Pro Chip running macOS Venture 13.0.1 and have Python 3.9.6 installed. When trying to run the following command(s):
pip install anonympy

pip3 install anonympy

I get the following output:
Collecting anonympy
  Using cached anonympy-0.3.7.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error in anonympy setup command: 'python_requires' must be a string containing valid version specifiers; Invalid specifier: '>=3.6*'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

I tried this on Colab and on a virtual environment running the same python version locally, getting the same build wheel error both times. I have also tried running the following command to no avail.
pip(3) install --upgrade setuptools

Is there a problem with the package, or am I missing something?

It seems it's an error in the package that is not compatible with the last PyPi version.
You can install it directly with pip+git :
pip install git+https://github.com/ArtLabss/open-data-anonymizer.git
Related Github Issue : https://github.com/ArtLabss/open-data-anonymizer/issues/26
